# Ember ContainerView of RC1 not getting currentState

Tags: ember.js

In earlier versions i added childViews in `init()` method of ContainerView. So while migrating to newer version, I am getting error. I found that it is not able to get the `CurrentState` of the containerView. It works well if i add the `childViews` in `didInsertElement`. For my code its important that the childViews to be added in `init()`. Here is the jsfiddle of same. http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/p73jq/7/

Answer (score 0):

corrected the error..its actually very silly mistake...i needed to add `this._super()` in the beginning of the method...in previous it worked even if i call `this._super()` in the end of `init()` method..here is working jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/p73jq/11/